# Does filter in web.xml gets executed when we forward the request?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, servlets, forward

When i forward the request from servlet to another, does filters described in web.xml get executed?
In fact i am not sure whether web.xm comes in to picture or not in case of request forward?
I know it happens in case of redirect as its  fresh request from browser but not sure about
forward?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default - no.

You can enable execution of specific filter on forward by adding

```
<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
```

to its `<filter-mapping>`.

Comment: so when we forward the request web.xml comes in to picture and is used for finding servlet mapping etc.Is that correct? Regarding filter execution, it depend upon <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>